# Why does Xcode create invalid code?

Tags: ios, xcode

When you start typing a function, Xcode will try to auto complete it if you press tab.  But instead, you end up with something like this:

```
override func override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
```

I started typing `function viewDidAppear` and then pressed tab.  That's when I got the above gibberish.  Is there some way to use the auto complete without it creating invalid code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you should just start typing viewD and then press tab on your desired method (in this case viewDidAppear) and it will add the "override func" bit for you.

It is there to help you type less and not need to type the override func every time before it auto fills for you. It is annoying when you are used to typing it but if you can train yourself to just start typing the function names it saves a lot of typing and is much quicker.